# Grails Events Push Failed to Initialize Atmosphere Framework

Tags: grails, atmosphere, ajax-push

Deploying a `Grails` project that uses `Events Push Plugin`. I keep getting this error.

> Production environment: Tomcat 7.39
>
> Server: CentOS, Java Version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6
>   1.10.8) (rhel-1.27.1.10.8.el5_8-x86_64) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
>
> Plugin version: events-push:1.0.M7

The project works fine in development mode.

```
2013-05-02 14:35:57,388 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR cpr.AtmosphereFramework  - Failed to initialize Atmosphere Framework
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/plugin/platform/events/push/EventsPushHandler$1
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.push.EventsPushHandler.init(EventsPushHandler.java:111)
    at org.atmosphere.util.AtmosphereFilterChain.init(AtmosphereFilterChain.java:125)
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor$FilterChainServletWrapper.init(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:318)
    at org.atmosphere.handler.ReflectorServletProcessor.init(ReflectorServletProcessor.java:210)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.initAtmosphereHandler(AtmosphereFramework.java:1003)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:570)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:498)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:197)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.MeteorServlet.init(MeteorServlet.java:115)
    at org.grails.plugin.platform.events.push.GrailsMeteorServlet.init(GrailsMeteorServlet.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.plugin.platform.events.push.EventsPushHandler$1
    ... 16 more
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/smaldini/grails-events-push/issues/26